# Extending controller have an undefined form when submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Ok, I have a main controller and an other one where I extend the main (to display different layout).

Main controller:

```
function CustomerInformationController(...) {
    var vm = this;
    ...

    vm.save = function() {
        if (angular.isDefined(vm.guestAccountForm)) {
            ...
        }
        ...
```

Main template:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerInformationController as customerInformation" class="customer-information">
    <form name="customerInformation.guestAccountForm">
    ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Extend controller:

```
function CustomerInformationControllerExtent($controller, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    // Extend Product Controller.
    angular.extend(this, $controller('CustomerInformationController', { $scope: $scope }));
```

Extend template (I want to be able to redesigned this template and override it):

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerInformationControllerExtent as customerInformation" class="customer-information">
    <form name="customerInformation.guestAccountForm">
    ...
    </form>
</div>
```

When I'm using only the main control everything is fine, but in the controller extend, when I try to check if the form is valid, `vm.guestAccountForm` is undefined.

BUT, when I try with `this` (`this.guestAccountForm`) it's ok.

Am I missing something with extend function?

Comment: I did some kind of hack with a method I call from extend controller to reinit vm variable....

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to inject the `vm` object as a local:

```
function CustomerInformationControllerExtent($controller, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    // Extend Product Controller.
    angular.extend(this, $controller('CustomerInformationController', { vm  vm}));
```

Then use the injected `vm` object:

```
function CustomerInformationController(vm) {
    ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶v̶m̶ ̶=̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶;̶
    ...

    vm.save = function() {
        if (angular.isDefined(vm.guestAccountForm)) {
            ...
        }
        ...
```

The `this` object of the `xController` is different from the `this` object of the `xControllerExtent` controller. That is why `angular.extend` is used. It copies properties from one `this` object to the other.

Frankly, I don't think this is the wisest approach. If you want to share common functions between controllers, put those common functions in a service.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give it a try. Honestly, it's the first time I need that kind of approach. The main reason I did it this way, I wan't the core code of controllers at one specific place, and develop specific stuff in extended controller. It can evolve and change as well, I will see.